# Sefirat HaOmer tag

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

Right now the [sefirat-ha-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer) tag is used for both the mitzva deorayta of counting the Omer, as well as the unrelated period of mourning that happens to coincide with these days. The two are (at least on a peshat level) completely unrelated. Perhaps they should be differentiated?

Comment: Do we really need a tag just for the mitzvah of counting the omer?

Comment: @MonicaCellio we have less-applicable tags. I see at least three questions about counting (and I just glanced at the first few questions of this tag)

Comment: Deorayta? I think we hold nowadays that it is derabanan.

Comment: @DoubleAA **[מצוה זו על כל איש מישראל, ובכל מקום ובכל זמן](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/8607.htm)**

Comment: @Vram I didn't know we paskined out of the Mishneh Torah. http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%98#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.AA.D7.A4.D7.98_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91

Comment: @DoubleAA look at Seif 3, where he defends Rambam with the gemara. Doesn't seem to me that the Aruch Hashulchan decides one way or another. (Besides, who is "we"?)

Comment: @Vram The AH always defends the Rambam's shittah when it's questioned (at least he says that in his hakdama), but that doesn't mean he paskins like him. See also the second Beiur Halacha on 489 where he claims that Maran HaShulchan Aruch and the Tur agree with me. (I wasn't aware you were Teimani...)

Comment: @DoubleAA I wasn't aware that I'm Yemenite either. That doesn't mean that I accepted the Biur Halacha or AH (or any single work) as my conclusive pesak halacha.

Comment: @DoubleAA besides for the Mishnah, of course!

Comment: @Vram I don't think either of those is necessarily a conclusive pesak halacha. But I do think that it's hard to prove what we hold nowadays by quoting one rishon, even if it is the Nesher HaGadol. You're welcome to bring other sources to the table, but Tur, Shulchan Aruch, Mishnah Berurah and Aruch HaShulchan beshem Rov Poskim is לענ"ד a יש על מי לסמוך

Comment: @DoubleAA In terms of what the Shulchan Aruch holds: check out the Gr"a. I'm not very clear on his conclusions, but if I understand correctly, he holds that the shulchan aruch is choshesh for the opinion that its min hatorah. (See, for example, his comment on Seif 8.) Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Vram Indeed he does seem to imply that, but ends up in a tzarich iyun because of it. I'm not sure why he goes that way. The Mishna Berurah's explanation of the din is satisfying and doesn't involve holding like a lot of weird shittot. So tzarich iyun on the Gra.

Comment: @DoubleAA It isn't a safek whether it's d'oraisa or d'Rabbanan, which is why we continue counting without a brachah if a night was missed?

Comment: @DonielF I don't know what deorayta or derabanan has to do with continuing if you missed a day, or with anything to do with the blessing.

Comment: @DoubleAA Safek d'oraisa l'chumra, so we still count, but safek d'Rabbanan l'Kula, so there's no bracha

Comment: @DonielF The obligation to bless is derabanan according to everyone, so indeed sefeko lehakel. That has nothing to do with the obligation of the mitzva to count. See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/71788/759

Comment: @DoubleAA In hacha nami. But if sefiras ha'omer isn't said, why are you making the Bracha? Therefore, since we're mesupak about whether to count or not, we're meikel on the Bracha in spite of being machmir on the counting.

Comment: @DonielF What does this have to do with the machloket about whether counting nowadays is deorayta or derabanan? Either way no brakha if theres any doubt.

Answer (score 3):

An amendment to @msh210's answer: have two tags, [sefirat-haomer-counting](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-haomer-counting) and [communal-mourning](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communal-mourning), with the latter covering both this period and the three weeks.  If that grows too large over time we can split it.

Comment: On second thought, I don't know if combining all the communal mourning questions is such a good idea. As of now we have 13 [tag:nine-days] and 11 [tag:three-weeks] plus ~20 from [tag:sefirat-haomer]. Combined, that's bigger than most tags we have now. I'm not saying it's for sure a bad idea; just that I'm second guessing.

Comment: How big *should* tags be?  I thought having 50+ questions in a tag was fairly normal for SE; in fact, you can't even get the tag badges until there are at least 100 questions, which seems to indicate design intent.  (Not that tag badges are a motivating factor; I'm just pointing out the threshold.)

Comment: Under this scheme, would questions about Sefira-time mourning get both of these tags? If that's so, I support this alternative.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I would say yes, in that case apply both tags.

Comment: MonicaCellio, and then the currently [tag:nine-days]- and [tag:three-weeks]-tagged questions would be tagged with their current tags and also [tag:communal-mourning]? That seems redundant. Ping @IsaacMoses too.

Comment: @msh210 I would imagine they should only get the time-specific tag in addition if the question is unique to that time-period.

Comment: @msh210, That's the standard subset problem - just like, e.g. Sukkot and Yom Tov. I'd suggest that if the question is about mourning during the Nine Days, it should get both tags. If it's about communal mourning spanning the Nine Days and Sefira, it should either get just communal-mourning or that and the two period-based tags (the latter mostly if we're comparing and contrasting).

Comment: @DoubleAA, IsaacMoses, the problem in this case is that I doubt there will be many questions about _s'fira_ **and** the three weeks or nine days (unless such as compare/contrast them), simply because the rules for the one time period differ from the rules for the other.

Comment: Ping @IsaacMoses too.

Comment: @msh210 I imagine most shaving/haircut/music/wedding questions fit nicely both ways. It's really when you hit the nine-days that you start having differences: meat/wine/bathing/laundry.

Comment: I erred in my previous comment.  I think communal-mourning questions should just get the communal-mourning tag -- sefira, nine days, three weeks, all of 'em.  Tags are buckets, and it's ok to have to root around in the bucket a bit if you're looking for something specific.  Otherwise we're going to end up with questions with three different mourning tags, which seems cumbersome.  Ping @IsaacMoses.

Comment: Ping @msh210 too.

Answer (score -1):

I agree: it should be split. I suggest [sefirat-haomer--counting](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-haomer--counting) and [sefirat-haomer--mourning](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-haomer--mourning).

Comment: I think we should have the sefirat haomer tag that we have.  Then add the aveilut tag if that is relevant to the mourning.

Comment: @AdamMosheh, would you please post that as an answer? Maybe it will get more net votes than my answer and we can adopt it as the community's will.

Comment: How do entries tagged sefirat-haomer-mourning differ from those about the three weeks?  If we want a separate tag for this, should it be more general, like mourning-periods?  (I'm not sure how you distinguish from plain old mourning after a death; I assume they're different enough that we'd need to.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio, the rules for the three weeks differ from those for _s'fira_, and the rules for either differs from those for actual mourning after a death. There is of course a good deal of overlap. Perhaps you're right, though, that we should have only [tag:mourning-periods]. Would you please post that as an answer? Maybe it will get more net votes than my answer and we can adopt it as the community's will.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Can I suggest you call it [tag:communal-mourning] and adjust the current tag to [tag:personal-mourning]?

Comment: @msh210, thanks for the explanation.  I'll post that as an answer (taking DoubleAA's amendment).  If the tag grows large we can always split it.

Answer (score -1):

For the sake of completeness (and so people can explicitly vote this option):

One tag is sufficient; there aren't that many questions on this and we have a lot of tags already.

Comment: Am I allowed to downvote this if my opinion was already presented in the question?

Comment: Ex-Vram, I think that's fine.  The question doesn't show up in the ranking of answers, after all.