# Should there be an [A-cappella] tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, retagging

Should there be an [a-cappella](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-cappella) tag for the many questions that are now tagged [sefirat-ha-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer), [three-weeks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-weeks), and [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)?

According to a [quick search](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer+music+three-weeks), six questions come up:

- [Is it o.k. to watch "American Idol" during the Omer and the Three Weeks?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/977/is-it-o-k-to-watch-american-idol-during-the-omer-and-the-three-weeks)
- [What are the limits of "music"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17636/what-are-the-limits-of-music)
- [Listening to Recorded Music *Privately* During the 3 Weeks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29832/listening-to-recorded-music-privately-during-the-3-weeks)
- [Listening to music while studying/writing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43937/listening-to-music-while-studying-writing)
- [What are some good sources of a cappella music for Sefiras HaOmer?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81991/what-are-some-good-sources-of-a-cappella-music-for-sefiras-haomer)
- [How are albums such as AKAPella considered a capella?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/82015/how-are-albums-such-as-akapella-considered-a-capella)

Then there's also [these 15 questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer+music+-three-weeks) that have the [sefirat-ha-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer) and [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) tags but not the [three-weeks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-weeks) tag:

- [are you allowed get music lessons during sefirah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81996/are-you-allowed-get-music-lessons-during-sefirah)
- [Sounding the Shofar during the Omer?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57883/sounding-the-shofar-during-the-omer)
- [Do any communities permit music during Sefira?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57760/do-any-communities-permit-music-during-sefira)
- [can a person take music lessons during sefirah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57443/can-a-person-take-music-lessons-during-sefirah)
- [Can one listen to music while he works to make the work less dull?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/57260/can-one-listen-to-music-while-he-works-to-make-the-work-less-dull)
- [How is one allowed to listen to live music on Yom Ha'atzma'ut when it's during sefirah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37731/how-is-one-allowed-to-listen-to-live-music-on-yom-haatzmaut-when-its-during-s)
- [Music during Sefiras HaOmer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37285/music-during-sefiras-haomer)
- [Is one allowed to listen to music during Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15732/is-one-allowed-to-listen-to-music-during-pesach)
- [May musicians practice their instruments during Sefirah?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/may-musicians-practice-their-instruments-during-sefirah)
- [Why should A Capella music be allowed during Sefirah/Three Weeks?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/7002/why-should-a-capella-music-be-allowed-during-sefirah-three-weeks)
- [Sefira Restrictions During Chol Hamoed Pesach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6957/sefira-restrictions-during-chol-hamoed-pesach)
- [Music on lag baomer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1320/music-on-lag-baomer)
- [Kids listening to music in sefira: what age](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1189/kids-listening-to-music-in-sefira-what-age)
- [Live Vs. Recorded Music during the Omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1046/live-vs-recorded-music-during-the-omer)
- [Music on Rosh Chodesh Iyar?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/880/music-on-rosh-chodesh-iyar)

Finally, [seven more questions](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music+three-weeks+-sefirat-ha-omer) tagged [music](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) and [three-weeks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-weeks) but not [sefirat-ha-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer).

- [Source for prohibition to listen to music during the 3 weeks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43580/source-for-prohibition-to-listen-to-music-during-the-3-weeks)
- [Listening to music during the 3 weeks?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43577/listening-to-music-during-the-3-weeks)
- [Sleeping Music during the Three Weeks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43462/sleeping-music-during-the-three-weeks)
- [Do the restrictions start at night or day?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43363/do-the-restrictions-start-at-night-or-day)
- ["I was waiting for my flight and a concert broke out."](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29870/i-was-waiting-for-my-flight-and-a-concert-broke-out)
- [What to do when tisha b'av is nidcheh (this year)?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18089/what-to-do-when-tisha-bav-is-nidcheh-this-year)
- [Staying to enjoy the unexpected playing of recorded music during the 3 weeks/9 days](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/staying-to-enjoy-the-unexpected-playing-of-recorded-music-during-the-3-weeks-9-d)

Is an [a-cappella](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-cappella) tag called for here? Or should we leave them alone?

The reason I propose this is because of the fact that there are three different groups above - those that include [sefirat-ha-omer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sefirat-ha-omer), those that include [three-weeks](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/three-weeks), and those that include both. An [a-cappella](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-cappella) tag would group all 28 questions together, without resorting to figuring out how the question is tagged. Granted, many of them are specific to sefira or three weeks and probably should keep those tags.

Comment: similar https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/988/759

Answer (score 2):

Many of the linked questions don't have anything to do with a capella music, in particular. For example, in the first set of six example questions, the first four are all about music in general, and only the last two are about vocal music, specifically. Therefore, I do not think that this whole class of questions should be tagged `a-capella`, as that would be misleading.

The real common theme here is restrictions on music during periods of mourning. (Similar restrictions on people who are mourning recently-departed close relatives would also fit into this general category.) Therefore, I recommend that questions on this topic be tagged `mourning-aveilus` and `music`, and that then, all of them will be findable by [searching for these two tags together](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music+mourning-aveilus).

A possible alternative would be to make a special tag for "music restrictions in mourning," but:

- I'm unaware of a concise term already in general use that means this. As explained above, I don't think that "a capella" does without being misleading.
- That would mean that all such questions would deserve three tags related to this concept instead of two, further crowding out other tags.